# Taylor expansion of $\log(z^2-3z+2)$ at z = 0

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series of the function $$f(z) = \log(z^2-3z+2) \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \left\{1,2 \right\} $$ at $z = 0$ and calculate the radius of convergence for the resultant series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(z) = \log(z^2-3z+2) \implies f'(z)=\frac{2 z-3}{z^2-3 z+2}=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}$$
So, making the story short,
$$f'(z)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+2^{-(n+1)})\,z^n$$ Integrate termwise
$$f(z)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1+2^{-(n+1)}\right) }{n+1} z^{n+1}+K=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1+2^{-n}}{n}z^n+K$$ and since $f(0)=\log(2)$ then $K=\log(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use $f=\ln2+\ln(1-z)+\ln(1-z/2)$. I'll leave you to work out the Taylor series. Hopefully, you can see which term determines the radius of convergence.